# python/perl script for text extraction

Tags: python, regex, perl, text

I am currently involved in mathematics of machine learning (NLP to be precise). While on the task I have encountered a  problem. I want to print out lines containing any of the following regexes:

1)fbchat

2)fb_timeline

3)Facebook Wall Post

into a separate text files, one for each string mentioned above.

Then in each of the resulting text files, I would like to sort each line with respect to the **thread ID** field of the Database mentioned in the very first line of *messaged.dmp*.
I am a theoretical person with very less programming experience.

The download link to the database dump is given below

[messages.dmp](http://dropcanvas.com/dvhhl)

Update:

This is the script I tried to write:

```
import re
from sys import argv

scrip, file_name = argv

dfile = open(file_name, 'r')

for line in dfile:
    if re.match("fbchat", line):
        print line
```

But the script performs nothing.

Comment: I understand that you are `a theoretical person with very less programming experience` but please refer to the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) You can't ask `questions you haven't tried to find an answer for` you need to show your work.

Comment: @KobiK I have updated my question...pls go through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following **text** `file.txt`:

```
text1
fbchat !
text2
Facebook Wall Post line
```

You can use the following **code**:

```
# open the file
with open('c:\\file.txt') as f:
    # read all lines as list
    lines = f.readlines()
# iterate over the list
for line in lines:
    # if any of the the strings in the list is in the line print it (using list comprehensions)
    if any(s in line for s in ['fbchat', 'fb_timeline', 'Facebook Wall Post']):
        # print but first remove new line character
        print line.strip("\n")
```

**Output:**

```
fbchat !
Facebook Wall Post line
```

You can read more about [Python With](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm), [Python: List Comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk), [Strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Comment: Thanx this worked .... but could you pls point out what mistakes were there in my script....that would be helpful as i intend to learn..............and thanks for sharing additional resources....its very hard for newbie to filter down enormous amount of material that google churns up for any reference query.....

Comment: Glad it helped, You problem was with understanding `re.match()`, You can read this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm) about regex and python it's short and easy, Also you can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13423624/1982962) post.

Comment: but i am unable to come up with a solution to the second part ....that is if i get all lines containing **fbchat** in a chat file...how will i be able to sort these lineS based on the **thread ID** field in them...pls go thru ...thank you