# python capture from regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am writing a regex to find a `?` and capture everything before that.  Here's what I have so far.

```
f = 'file.doc?gs_f'
f1 = re.search(r'(\?)',f)
print(f[:f1.start()]) #prints "file.doc"
```

How do I use the regex to capture everything before the `?`. The is something called a look behind but I am unsure how to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract string with Python re.match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423624/extract-string-with-python-re-match)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I get everything before a : in a string Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387415/how-would-i-get-everything-before-a-in-a-string-python)

Comment: ... also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171045/python-regular-expression-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
^[^\?]+
```

And use findall:

```
f = 'file.doc?gs_f'
f1 = re.findall("^[^\?]+",f)
```

You can see a regex working below for any kind of string:
[Regex_Working](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5E%5B%5E%5C%3F%5D%2B&test_string=file.docfsfs%3Fgs_f&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: I wanted to get better with regexpressions.

Comment: Oh, I see, okay, give me a minute, I'll make edits and get back with regex answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I know it has something to do with using `<=` but I tried placing that but I kept getting `none` when I print `f1.group(0)` or `f1.group(1)`

Comment: Get rid of the backslash in square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple possibilities:

1. Either everything not a question mark: `[^?]+`
2. Or a lazy quantifier with capturing groups: `(.+?)\?`
3. Or a positive lookahead: `.+?(?=\?)`

See the corresponding demos on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com) ([**1**](https://regex101.com/r/bgHti4/1), [**2**](https://regex101.com/r/bgHti4/2) and [**3**](https://regex101.com/r/bgHti4/3)).

Comment: Thanks everyone for all of the help

Answer (score 1):

You do not need look behind.

```
f = 'file.doc?gs_f'
re.search(r'([\w\.]*(?=\?))',f).group(0)
```

A good here [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called Positive Look Ahead. You have to look ahead till `?` comes. Here is the Regex which is performing your reqt. let me know if you have any question.

Regex: `'.*(?=\?)'`

Here,
`.*` will pull everything.
`(?=)` is a positive look ahead
`\` escape character for question mark symbol. As question mark symbol is Quantifier in Regex.